# Elasticsearch - Replicas is unassigned after reopen index INDEX_REOPENED error

Tags: elasticsearch

I closed my index and reopen it and now my shards can't assigne.

```
curl -s -XGET localhost:9201/_cat/shards?h=index,shard,prirep,state,unassigned.reason | grep UNASSIGNED
2018.03.27-team-logs 2 r UNASSIGNED INDEX_REOPENED
2018.03.27-team-logs 5 r UNASSIGNED INDEX_REOPENED
2018.03.27-team-logs 3 r UNASSIGNED INDEX_REOPENED
2018.03.27-team-logs 4 r UNASSIGNED INDEX_REOPENED
2018.03.27-team-logs 1 r UNASSIGNED INDEX_REOPENED
2018.03.27-team-logs 0 r UNASSIGNED INDEX_REOPENED
2018.03.28-team-logs 2 r UNASSIGNED INDEX_REOPENED
2018.03.28-team-logs 5 r UNASSIGNED INDEX_REOPENED
2018.03.28-team-logs 3 r UNASSIGNED INDEX_REOPENED
2018.03.28-team-logs 4 r UNASSIGNED INDEX_REOPENED
2018.03.28-team-logs 1 r UNASSIGNED INDEX_REOPENED
2018.03.28-team-logs 0 r UNASSIGNED INDEX_REOPENED
```

Could anybody explain me what does error means and how to solve it? Before I closed it everything works fine. I configured 6 shards and 1 replica. Installed Elasticsearch 6.2.

**EDIT:**

Output of `curl -XGET "localhost:9201/_cat/shards"`:

```
2018.03.29-team-logs 1 r STARTED    1739969 206.2mb 10.207.46.247 elk-es-data-hot-1.platform.osdc2.mall.local
2018.03.29-team-logs 1 p STARTED    1739969   173mb 10.206.46.246 elk-es-data-hot-2.platform.osdc1.mall.local
2018.03.29-team-logs 2 p STARTED    1739414 169.9mb 10.207.46.247 elk-es-data-hot-1.platform.osdc2.mall.local
2018.03.29-team-logs 2 r STARTED    1739414 176.3mb 10.207.46.248 elk-es-data-hot-2.platform.osdc2.mall.local
2018.03.29-team-logs 4 p STARTED    1740185   186mb 10.206.46.247 elk-es-data-hot-1.platform.osdc1.mall.local
2018.03.29-team-logs 4 r STARTED    1740185 169.4mb 10.206.46.246 elk-es-data-hot-2.platform.osdc1.mall.local
2018.03.29-team-logs 5 r STARTED    1739660 164.3mb 10.207.46.248 elk-es-data-hot-2.platform.osdc2.mall.local
2018.03.29-team-logs 5 p STARTED    1739660 180.1mb 10.206.46.246 elk-es-data-hot-2.platform.osdc1.mall.local
2018.03.29-team-logs 3 p STARTED    1740606 171.2mb 10.207.46.248 elk-es-data-hot-2.platform.osdc2.mall.local
2018.03.29-team-logs 3 r STARTED    1740606 173.4mb 10.206.46.247 elk-es-data-hot-1.platform.osdc1.mall.local
2018.03.29-team-logs 0 r STARTED    1740166 169.7mb 10.207.46.247 elk-es-data-hot-1.platform.osdc2.mall.local
2018.03.29-team-logs 0 p STARTED    1740166   187mb 10.206.46.247 elk-es-data-hot-1.platform.osdc1.mall.local
2018.03.28-team-logs 1 p STARTED    2075020 194.2mb 10.207.46.248 elk-es-data-hot-2.platform.osdc2.mall.local
2018.03.28-team-logs 1 r UNASSIGNED                               
2018.03.28-team-logs 2 p STARTED    2076268 194.9mb 10.206.46.247 elk-es-data-hot-1.platform.osdc1.mall.local
2018.03.28-team-logs 2 r UNASSIGNED                               
2018.03.28-team-logs 4 p STARTED    2073906 194.9mb 10.207.46.247 elk-es-data-hot-1.platform.osdc2.mall.local
2018.03.28-team-logs 4 r UNASSIGNED                               
2018.03.28-team-logs 5 p STARTED    2072921   195mb 10.207.46.248 elk-es-data-hot-2.platform.osdc2.mall.local
2018.03.28-team-logs 5 r UNASSIGNED                               
2018.03.28-team-logs 3 p STARTED    2074579 194.1mb 10.206.46.246 elk-es-data-hot-2.platform.osdc1.mall.local
2018.03.28-team-logs 3 r UNASSIGNED                               
2018.03.28-team-logs 0 p STARTED    2073349 193.9mb 10.207.46.248 elk-es-data-hot-2.platform.osdc2.mall.local
2018.03.28-team-logs 0 r UNASSIGNED                               
2018.03.27-team-logs 1 p STARTED     356769  33.5mb 10.207.46.246 elk-es-data-warm-1.platform.osdc2.mall.local
2018.03.27-team-logs 1 r UNASSIGNED                               
2018.03.27-team-logs 2 p STARTED     356798  33.6mb 10.206.46.244 elk-es-data-warm-2.platform.osdc1.mall.local
2018.03.27-team-logs 2 r UNASSIGNED                               
2018.03.27-team-logs 4 p STARTED     356747  33.7mb 10.207.46.246 elk-es-data-warm-1.platform.osdc2.mall.local
2018.03.27-team-logs 4 r UNASSIGNED                               
2018.03.27-team-logs 5 p STARTED     357399  33.8mb 10.207.46.245 elk-es-data-warm-2.platform.osdc2.mall.local
2018.03.27-team-logs 5 r UNASSIGNED                               
2018.03.27-team-logs 3 p STARTED     357957  33.7mb 10.206.46.245 elk-es-data-warm-1.platform.osdc1.mall.local
2018.03.27-team-logs 3 r UNASSIGNED                               
2018.03.27-team-logs 0 p STARTED     356357  33.4mb 10.207.46.245 elk-es-data-warm-2.platform.osdc2.mall.local
2018.03.27-team-logs 0 r UNASSIGNED                               
.kibana                  0 p STARTED          2  12.3kb 10.207.46.247 elk-es-data-hot-1.platform.osdc2.mall.local
.kibana                  0 r UNASSIGNED
```

Output of `curl -XGET "localhost:9201/_cat/nodes"`:

```
10.207.46.248  8 82 0 0.07 0.08 0.11 d - elk-es-data-hot-2
10.206.46.245  9 64 0 0.04 0.11 0.08 d - elk-es-data-warm-1
10.207.46.249 11 90 0 0.00 0.01 0.05 m * elk-es-master-2
10.207.46.245  9 64 0 0.00 0.01 0.05 d - elk-es-data-warm-2
10.206.46.247 12 82 0 0.00 0.06 0.08 d - elk-es-data-hot-1
10.206.46.244 10 64 0 0.08 0.04 0.05 d - elk-es-data-warm-2
10.207.46.243  5 86 0 0.00 0.01 0.05 d - elk-kibana
10.206.46.248 10 92 1 0.04 0.18 0.24 m - elk-es-master-1
10.206.46.246  6 82 0 0.02 0.07 0.09 d - elk-es-data-hot-2
10.207.46.247  9 82 0 0.06 0.06 0.05 d - elk-es-data-hot-1
10.206.46.241  6 91 0 0.00 0.02 0.05 m - master-test
10.206.46.242  8 89 0 0.00 0.02 0.05 d - es-kibana
10.207.46.246  8 64 0 0.00 0.02 0.05 d - elk-es-data-warm-1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is expected behaviour.

Elasticsearch will not put primary and replica shard on the same 
node. You will need at least 2 nodes to have have 1 replica.

You can simply set replica to 0

```
PUT */_settings
{
    "index" : {
    "number_of_replicas" : 0
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

After running following request

```
GET /_cluster/allocation/explain?pretty
```

we can see response here

https://pastebin.com/1ag1Z7jL

> "explanation" : "there are too many copies of the shard allocated to
>   nodes with attribute [datacenter], there are [2] total configured
>   shard copies for this shard id and [3] total attribute values,
>   expected the allocated shard count per attribute [2] to be less than
>   or equal to the upper bound of the required number of shards per
>   attribute [1]"

Probbably you have zone setting used. Elasticsearch will avoid to put primary and replica shard in same zone
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/allocation-awareness.html

> With ordinary awareness, if one zone lost contact with the other zone,
>   Elasticsearch would assign all of the missing replica shards to a
>   single zone. But in this example, this sudden extra load would cause
>   the hardware in the remaining zone to be overloaded.
>
> Forced awareness solves this problem by NEVER allowing copies of the
>   same shard to be allocated to the same zone.
>
> For example, lets say we have an awareness attribute called zone, and
>   we know we are going to have two zones, zone1 and zone2. Here is how
>   we can force awareness on a node:
>
> cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.force.zone.values: zone1,zone2 
>   cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes: zone

Comment: I have 3 master nodes and 3 data nodes.

Comment: Could you post whole list of shards curl -XGET "http://localhost:9201/_cat/shards" and nodes curl -XGET "http://localhost:9201/_cat/nodes"

Comment: I edit my question. As you can see, today index 2018.03.29-team-logs do not have this problem, other indices have been closed and reopen. I have splitted nodes to warm and hot that is why i using just 4 data nodes.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing to check GET /_cluster/allocation/explain?pretty

Comment: The output was too long, so i update it here https://pastebin.com/1ag1Z7jL. Is that way how to upload it here? For other people who will have the same problem in few weeks or months.

Comment: Looks like you defined different zones in your config. Check updated answer